# What is the ServiceProviderId to provision a SharePoint Online connection for Azure bot

Tags: azure, authentication, sharepoint, botframework, bots

I'm trying to provision a bot resource in Azure with two connection (an Azure Active Directory V2 and a sharepoint Online) using ARM template (see bellow).

I was able to make it work for AADv2 successfully, and everything works fine.
I was able to make it work when I provision the resource manually.
Sadly, you can't export the templates for a bot resource...And I can't succeed to make it work for Sharepoint online, and the only parameter I don't know what to set is the Service Provider Id, as I was able to test setting the other manually.
When i use the same as AADv2, the connection provisionned is AADv2 (30dd229c-58e3-4a48-bdfd-91ec48eb906c)...

My template to provision this resources is:

```
{
                "name": "[concat(parameters('botId'),'/',parameters('SharepointConnectionName'))]",
                "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/Connections",
                "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
                "location": "global",
                "tags": {},
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
                },
                "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
                "properties": {
                    "clientId": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionClientId')]",
                    "clientSecret": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionClientSecret')]",
                    "scopes": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionScopes')]",
                    "serviceProviderId": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionServiceProviderId')]",
                    "serviceProviderDisplayName": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionServiceProviderDisplayName')]",
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "key": "tenantId",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionTenantID')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "clientId",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionClientId')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "clientSecret",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionClientSecret')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "GrantType",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionGrantType')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "LoginURL",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionLoginURL')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "DiscoveryURL",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionDiscoveryURL')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "ResourceURL",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionResourceURL')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Capability",
                            "value": "[parameters('SharepointConnectionCapabilityURL')]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.BotService/botServices/', parameters('botId'))]"
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `307d995f-f1ce-4918-bd3f-037685e9d241`?

I created two `SharePoint Online` connections using the browser/UI and after creating, I used Resource Explorer to show what I had created. Both use `307d995f-f1ce-4918-bd3f-037685e9d241` as the `serviceProviderId` when `serviceProviderDisplayName` is `SharePoint Online`.

Comment: I'll try that, and come back to tell if it works, thank you!

Comment: Sounds good. If so, please flag my answer as correct so that others will know.

Comment: It solved it! And in fact, I did not thought about resource explorer, so I can find all I need for my future connections.